# Integral $\int_{-3}^2 \frac{[x]}{[x]^2+2[x]+x^3}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I came across this question which was supposed to be solved in about $1$ or $2$ minutes, but I came across a severe roadblock.

The question was:

> Integrate $$\int_{-3}^2 \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{\lfloor x\rfloor^2+2\lfloor x \rfloor+x^3}dx$$

I split the integral into $5$ separate ones to substitute a known value of step $x$. But following that I had to use partial fractions with some weird numbers and that made it pretty long. How do I approach this sum?

Comment: Was this question on a exam, since it was supposed to be solved in a short time? Did you only have to circle a correct answer? Also do you know the final answer?

Comment: Yes it was in an exam and a friend asked me this. And yes there were options but I am not aware of the final answer

Comment: I see. So we only have to aproximate it since there were multiple choices, otherwise it's a mess indeed. Can your friend provide those multiple choices of the answer?

Comment: As Zacky commented, this is a real mess ! Guessing, that is almost to say dividing my age by the speed of the the wind, I would guess 2.

Comment: Well my friend says the options were fractions close to 1 but I don't think he remembers the exact options. But thanks for trying. I honestly can't find a way through this mess, so if any thought strikes you please mention it

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right we have to split the integral into 5:

$$I_1 = \int_{-3}^{-2}\frac{-3dx}{3 + x^3}$$

$$I_2 = \int_{-2}^{-1}\frac{-2dx}{x^3} = \frac{3}{4}$$

$$I_3 = \int_{-1}^{0}\frac{-dx}{-1 + x^3}$$

$$I_4 = 0$$

$$I_5 = \int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{3 + x^3}$$

Separately we try to find the integral

$$\int\frac{dx}{a^3 + x^3}$$

$$= \int(\frac{1}{3a^2(x + a)} + \frac{1}{3a^2}\frac{- x + 2a}{x^2 -ax + a^2})dx$$

$$= \int\frac{1}{3a^2}(\frac{1}{x + a} - \frac{x - \frac{a}{2} - \frac{3a}{2}}{(x - \frac{a}{2})^2 + (\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2})^2})dx$$

$$= \frac{1}{6a^2}ln\frac{(x + a)^2}{x^2 -ax + a^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}a^2}tan^{-1}\frac{2x - a}{\sqrt{3}a}$$

Using this formula we have

$$I = I_1 + I_2 + I_3 + I_4 + I_5 = 0.2748 + 0.75 + 0.8356 + 0 + 0.1615 = 2.0219$$

Comment: Something looks wrong in one of your integrals: I get $$I_3=\int_{-1}^0{-dx\over-1+x^3}=\int_0^1{dx\over1+x^3}\lt\int_0^1{dx\over1}=1\lt1.0281$$

Comment: I do not understand the second equality.  When you interchange the limits the upper limit should still be -1 not 1.  Also when you change the sign why the + before x^3 did not change.  As the arithmetic is very complicated when I plugged in the values of a and x please correct the numerical result if you find it is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps I should have written it as $\int_0^1{du\over1+u^3}$, with the substitution $x=-u$.

Comment: Sorry!  You are right.  It should be 0.8356.  I have made the change.